# node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: angular, npm

We are facing issue as mentioned in title.
When we are doing ng build than its shows an attached SS error to us.
WE have tried all possbile way as already shared in github / stackoverflow community. But still we are facing the same error.
Guys, please help us to resolve this issue. We are stuck in the deployment process.
Here, are my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
"@angular/service-worker": "~10.1.6",
"@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^3.1.1",
"angular-datatables": "10.0.0",
"angular-pipes": "^10.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"braintree-web": "^3.71.1",
"datatables.net": "^1.10.23",
"datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.23",
"datatables.net-buttons": "^1.7.1",
"datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.7.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jszip": "^3.6.0",
"laravel-echo": "^1.10.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
"ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
"ngx-drag-scroll": "^9.0.0-beta.4",
"ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
"ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-pipes": "^2.7.5",
"ngx-select-dropdown": "1.5.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.2",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"sweetalert2": "^10.15.7",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"uuid": "^8.3.2",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

},

[image: Angular error]

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 14.14.0
OS: linux x64
```

Answer (score 6):

My issue get resolved by adding stable version of  `ng2-material-dropdown` into my package.json as below :

[image]

After adding this try again `npm install` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you see the error path then it is pointing to the node modules. This seems like an issue of the `node_modules` only. You need to delete the `node_modules` folder and install it again.

Comment: we have already tried with deleting node_module and npm intsall, but still facing same issue. We are trying all process from yesterday

Comment: Then try to delete cache of npm (`npm cache clean --force`) and restore node_modules again

Comment: we are using `npm cache clear` command at every step.

Comment: Have you updated any version recently and started getting this?

Comment: no, we didn't updated any version

Answer (score 4):

Getting same error for **ng-recaptcha**
I fixed same problem by adding to **tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths": { "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"] }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35291#issuecomment-598118244

Answer (score 1):

Running `ng update` to move to Angular 11 might also fix this.

Comment: we have tried ng update command. but didn't get it resolved

Answer (score 1):

Check for the version compatibility. Your some modules are not compatible with angular version. You have to read the docs of modules before installing it and install the version which is accepted by angular.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could be that there's an issue in your node_modules folder. Try running `npm ci`

Comment: we have tried npm ci also, but still facing same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng2-material-dropdown version to stable version in package.json file and Run 'npm install'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version is not compatible. Had the same problem then resolved the problem by updating the version of @ngx-translate/core, eg: the @angular/core is 10.0.5 , then update the @ngx-translate/core to 13.0.0[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR0lC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue, downgrading the version to stable version in **package.json** will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

if you are angular 9 use the following and don't ask why but it will work

- npm uninstall angular-froala-wysiwyg
- npm i angular-froala-wysiwyg@4.0.15
- npm uninstall ngx-print
- npm i ngx-print@1.2.1
- npm install querystring      // Should be: "querystring": "0.2.1",
- npm i webpack -dev-server@3.11.0